# Regex Input Filter in zend framework 2

Tags: regex, zend-framework, zend-framework2

i add input filter by this parameters :

and the question is why zend framework 2 have problem with utf8 pattern

```
  $formInputFilter->add($inputFactory->createInput(array(
                        'name' => $field->attribute->id,
                        'required' => true,
                        'validators' => array(

                            array(
                                'name' => 'Regex',
                                'options' => array(
                                    'pattern' => '/^[0-9,\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]*/u',
                                    'messages' => array(
                                        'regexNotMatch'=>'number is not correct'
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    )
                )
                );
```

the error is :

```
preg_match(): Compilation failed: character value in \x{} or \o{} is too large at offset 15
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my urls. It works with any digits and characters

`'\/^\d{4},(?:\s|\w)+\/u*'`

https://regex101.com/r/mW4xJ4/2

`\/^\d(?:\s|\w)+\/u*`

You can see the explanations of each character here: https://regex101.com/r/mW4xJ4/1